# Scaled iFrame has visual tearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am scaling an iFrame using the following CSS:

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.56);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(0.56);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(0.56);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-zoom: 0.56;
```

The content is some CSS3 animation, that typically fills a screen size of 1280x720, but I am scaling the iFrame in a page so it fits into a container/"frame".

Now, I have used this on other pages, and it works perfectly, but on one page, where the iFrame is initially hidden, then shown after loading the iFrame source, I am getting visual tearing (in Chrome currently, I have no checked other browsers yet)

What could be a potential cause for the tearing?

Comment: Please provide full code (HTML and CSS) that will allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Could you provide the animation link? I just tested and it works fine (http://jsbin.com/nataqe/1/edit?css,js,output)

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Sadly the animation is only on my local server. I'll try to find a similar animation online. Yes your example works, but the page content is static. I edited your snippet to use my locally hosted animation, and I got the tearing issue.

Comment: So I got a copy of my animation uploaded (its very basic) https://fa1fa5576f0d115f33898abaa59cba544a8dd8fb-www.googledrive.com/host/0B6pUCGoQLw9iVl9YSTBjV3FiRUE HOWEVER this does not seem to "tear" but my local one is, constantly! Very odd...

Comment: Still no tearing for me http://jsbin.com/nataqe/3/edit?css,js,output , seems you got something messed up at your local config.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I have no idea what could be causing it. I'm wondering if its just a Chrome issue...

Comment: have no idea since we cant reproduce it